# calculating total and average of stock information

Tags: c, formula

So i have my program up and running but I am not getting the correct values that I should be. 
[image: Here is the report]

I am trying to get 49% instead of .49% and the average is also messed up? Is this just a simple messup on formulas or am i totally screwed? really confused and actually glad i got to this point but am feeling really stuck. any help would be greatful.

```
#include <stdio.h>
//prototypes
void getInputs(char*ticker,float*buyPrice,float*sellPrice);         //3.1
float getPrice(int whole,int num,int dem);                          //3.1.1
float calcGainLoss(float buyPrice,float sellPrice);                 //3.2
void showTransactionReport(char ticker[],float gainLoss);           //3.3
void showSummaryReport(float totGainLoss,int numOfTransactions);    //3.4

int main(void)
{
    char ticker[15];
    float gainLoss;
    float buyPrice;
    float sellPrice;
    float totGainLoss=0;
    int numOfTransactions=0;
    char answer;
    do{
        getInputs(ticker,&buyPrice,&sellPrice); //call 3.1/.1
        gainLoss=calcGainLoss(buyPrice,sellPrice); //call 3.2
        showTransactionReport(ticker,gainLoss); //call 3.3
        totGainLoss= totGainLoss + gainLoss;
        numOfTransactions++;
        printf("Would you like to do another transaction? (Y/y or N/n) ==> ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf(" %c", &answer);
    }while (answer == 'Y' || answer == 'y');

    showSummaryReport(totGainLoss,numOfTransactions);

    fflush(stdin);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
//function 3.1
void getInputs(char*ticker,float*buyPrice,float*sellPrice)
{
    int whole=0;
    int num=0;
    int dem=0;
    printf("Enter the stock ticker ==> ");
    scanf("%s",ticker);
    printf("Input buy price of %s ==> ",ticker);
    scanf("%d %d/%d",&whole,&num,&dem);
    *buyPrice=getPrice(whole,num,dem);
    printf("Input sell price==> ");
    scanf("%d %d/%d",&whole,&num,&dem);
    *sellPrice=getPrice(whole,num,dem);
}
float getPrice(int whole,int num,int dem)
{
    return whole + float(num) / float(dem);
}
float calcGainLoss(float buyPrice,float sellPrice)
{
    return 1 - (buyPrice / sellPrice);
}
void showTransactionReport(char ticker[0],float gainLoss)
{
    printf("Stock Description               Gain/Loss%\n");
    printf("=================               ==========\n");
    printf("%-17s               %10.2f %% \n",ticker,gainLoss);
}
void showSummaryReport(float totGainLoss,int numOfTransactions)
{
    printf("Total Gain/Loss:                %10.2f %% \n",totGainLoss);
    printf("Average Gain/Loss:              %10.2f %% \n",numOfTransactions / totGainLoss);
}
```

Comment: You should provide: input, expected output, actual output

Comment: my buyPrice input was 20 1/2, my sellPrice was 40 1/2, so I expected an output for the APPLE stock to be 49% gain and it was actually 0.49%. I expected the total gainloss to also be 49% and it turned out to be .49%. The average should also be 49% because there was only one input but ended up being 2.03%

Comment: To me this looks strange `return 1 - (buyPrice / sellPrice);` So if you sell for 1.000.000 times more than buy, the GainLoss will be close to 1. Is that what you want?

Comment: And "sell price" was ....?

Comment: well the formula my professor gave me to define gain was g = 1-(sellprice / buyprice) but that was giving me a negative value when it should have been a positive and the other way around also.

Comment: ok, I'm not into the formulas used for calculating GainLoss  - I'm also surprised that totalGainLoss can be calculated just by adding the individual GainLoss. But as I said - it's not my area so it may be correct. Anyway: For the 49% versus 0.49% it's just a matter of multiplying by 100. A number is not a percentage until you have multipled by 100.

Comment: ok so https://gyazo.com/f14423bf52f3a8e08e3f80930cc4233a that works for the total gainloss but the average is .01% is that correct?

Comment: Should `numOfTransactions / totGainLoss`be `totGainLoss / numOfTransactions` ?

Comment: yes you are correct. that worked on the change. thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure but I would expect: `gain = (sellprice - buyprice) / buyprice` which is the same as `gain = sellprice / buyprice - 1`. Are you sure you got the correct formula?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/f14423bf52f3a8e08e3f80930cc4233a with                100-(buyPrice/sellPrice), these are correct values right?

Comment: do `return 100 * (1 - (buyPrice / sellPrice));` (but I still think your formula must be wrong)

Comment: The gain/loss percentage should be calculated like this: `((sellprice/buyprice) - 1)*100` and total gain/loss is: `((totalSellPrices/totalBuyPrices) - 1)*100`

Comment: https://gyazo.com/745a4187c6531c57a64a70f64671b70c that isnt correct cause if i double my money thats 100% gain not 50% i think my original was correct at return 100 - (buyPrice / sellPrice);

Comment: @AlexLop. so for the total gain/loss do i need to input that somewhere in my code? if so where lol

Comment: Instead of `totGainLoss= totGainLoss + gainLoss;` do it separately for `sellprice` and `buyprice`. and calculate the `totalGainLoss` at the end

Comment: Let me know if you want me to summarize all my comments in one answer to your question.

Comment: @AlexLop. im more confused on when you say separate them. i dont think i really know how to start something like that ha i was only really told this way.

Answer (score -1):

The gain/loss percentage should be calculated like this: `((sellprice/buyprice) - 1)*100` --<*make sure `buyprice` is not 0!*>-- and total gain/loss is: `((totalSellPrices/totalBuyPrices) - 1)*100`.

To do so, just modify a little your main loop:

```
float totalBuyPrice = 0.0f;
float totalSellPrice = 0.0f;
do{
    getInputs(ticker,&buyPrice,&sellPrice); //call 3.1/.1
    gainLoss=calcGainLoss(buyPrice,sellPrice); //call 3.2
    showTransactionReport(ticker,gainLoss); //call 3.3
    //totGainLoss= totGainLoss + gainLoss;
    totalBuyPrice += buyPrice;
    totalSellPrice += sellPrice;
    numOfTransactions++;
    printf("Would you like to do another transaction? (Y/y or N/n) ==> ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf(" %c", &answer);
}while (answer == 'Y' || answer == 'y');
```

then in `showSummaryReport` do the appropriate changes:

```
void showSummaryReport(float totalBuyPrice, float totalSellPrice, int numOfTransactions)
{
    float totGainLoss = 0.0f;
    if (totalBuyPrice)
    {
        totGainLoss = (totalSellPrice/totalBuyPrice - 1)*100;
    }
    printf("Total Gain/Loss:                %10.2f %% \n",totGainLoss);
    printf("Average Gain/Loss:              %10.2f %% \n",totGainLoss / numOfTransactions);
}
```

Of course don't forget to update the functions and variable declarations.